# How to alter the keys in a dictionary in python

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
def vmm(v, M):
    d = {}
    domain = [(i,j) for i in M.D[0] for j in M.D[1]]
    for k in M.D[1]:
        for i in domain:
            if i[1] == k:
                f = 0
                f += M[i]*v[i[0]]
                d[i] = f
    return d
```

it returns:

{(3, 'b'): 0, (3, 'a'): 0, (1, 'b'): 2, (2, 'a'): -8, (3, 'c'): 0, (2, 'b'): 0, (2, 'c'): 0, (1, 'a'): 0, (1, 'c'): 0}

Which is almost what i want, i would like instead each key to be the second element of the tuple, so they keys will be 'a','b' or 'c', where the values are the sum of all the values with 'a', 'b','c' as a second element.

I have tried replacing the last line before the return statement with:

```
d[1][i] = f
```

This returns a dictionary with all values equal to zero, this is not what i want.

EDIT

```
def vector_matrix_mul(v, M):
    d = {}
    e = {}
    domain = [(i,j) for i in M.D[0] for j in M.D[1]]
    for k in M.D[1]:
        for i in domain:
            if i[1] == k:
                f = 0
                f += M[i]*v[i[0]]
                d[i] = f
    for i in d: 
        for m in M.D[1]: #{'a', 'b', 'c'}
            if i[1] == m:
                for k in M.D[0]:
                    F = 0
                    F += i[m,k]
                    e[m] = F
    return e
```

Still no luck, if someone could help me with this, i don't want to use extra modules, just want to fix my code please.

```
M = Mat(M.D,M.f)
v = Vec(v.D,v.f)
```

so M.D is the 'domain' of the matrix and M.f is the function of the matrix. 
similarly with the vector.

an example...

```
>>> v1 = Vec({1, 2, 3}, {1: 1, 2: 8})
>>> M1 = Mat(({1, 2, 3}, {'a', 'b', 'c'}), {(1, 'b'): 2, (2, 'a'):-1, (3, 'a'): 1, (3, 'c'): 7})
```

Note the different dimensions in the domain of v and M.

Comment: More descriptive variable names would make it easier to understand your code. Also, can you show an example of what `M.D` looks like?

Answer (score 1):

use a defaultdict using the key from the tuple and summing each value:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d=defaultdict(int)

domain = zip(M.D[0], M.D[1])
for vl, k in domain:
    d[k] +=  M[(vl,k)] * v[vl]
```

I don't understand where `for k in M.D[1]` comes into it as you already have all the M.D[1] items in your domain list.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I have understood your question. Let me try. 
To alter a key in dictionary:

- find if the key k_old exists
- copy its value to a variable v
- remove the entry corresponding to k_old from the dictionary
- add a new entry with new key k_new with value v

Comment: That sounds smashing! The method i am using is working! and i'm new to Python so don't want to ruin a good thing.

Comment: Could you suggest how to implement your suggestion?